# removeByUniqueId not working in my bootstrap-table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, delete-row, bootstrap-table

I tried to use this command giving one of the Id's in my table and it is not working.

```
$table.bootstrapTable('removeByUniqueId', "ID");


$( "#deleteUrl" ).click(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    $('#servicetable').bootstrapTable('removeByUniqueId', "test");
});
```

Here `#deleteUrl is my delete button ID and "test" is one of the ID's` in my table.

I refered this Link for this syntax

http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#methods/removeByUniqueId.html

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I did in this way.
I added `data-unique-id="My-id"` in my table.

```
<table class="table-striped" id="servicetable" data-unique-id="hostname" data-search="true"  data-show-refresh="true"    data-show-columns="true"  data-pagination="true" >
```

I have this `My-id` in my table which is unique.

So im accessing this and deleting the row.
Yay finally i did!

```
$table.bootstrapTable('removeByUniqueId', "DEMO UPGRADE");
```

Comment: so what is hostname and what does it have to do with your example?